# AE2A dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve this problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/AE2A/. I know the idea behind this, but I'm getting WA. Can someone help me with this?
my code is: https://ideone.com/rksW1p

```
for( int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for( int j=1; j<=sum; j++)
    {
        for( int k=1; k<=6 && k<j; k++)
        {
            A[i][j] += A[i-1][j-k];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the numbers on top of the die faces be

```
x1,x2,x3...
```

then we have to find the ways in which

```
x1+x2+x3+...+xn=sum where 1<=xi<=6
```

Now, the solution of this integral equation is `(sum-1)C(n-1).`
Hence the probability will be `((sum-1)C(n-1))/(6^n).`
The answer will be `[((sum-1)C(n-1))/(6^n)x100]`
Hope this helps..